# Highchart multiple bar charts in a single webpage

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to add more than one bar chart in one page, but when they are displayed just the last one is correctly displyed. In the others previous charts, the bar is not graphed

---

I have this 2 variables (GraphOptionsX and GraphSeriesX) for each chart.

```
var GraphOptions0 = {
    chart:{renderTo: null,type: 'bar',height: 200,width: 300},
    title:{text:null},
    subtitle:{text:null},
    xAxis:{
        categories:null
    },
    yAxis:{min:0,title:{text: null},labels:{overflow: 'justify'}},
    tooltip:{formatter:function(){return '' + this.x + ' = ' + this.y;}},
    plotOptions:{bar:{dataLabels:{enabled: true}}},
    legend:{enabled: false},
    credits:{enabled: false},
    exporting:{enabled: false},
    series:[]
};
var GraphSeries0 = {
        name:"",
        data:[],
        point:{events:{click: null}}
};
```

an after I'm generating the charts so (x = 0, 1,...):

```
var graphSeries = eval("GraphSeries" + x);

        graphSeries.name = "GraphSeries" + x;
        graphSeries.data.push({ y: parseInt(107),   color: 'red' });
        graphSeries.data.push({ y: parseInt(31),    color: 'blue' });
        graphSeries.data.push({ y: parseInt(635),   color: 'green' });
        graphSeries.data.push({ y: parseInt(203),   color: 'yellow' });
        graphSeries.data.push({ y: parseInt(2),     color: 'orange' });
        graphSeries.point.events.click = function() {
            alert ('Category: '+ this.category +', value: '+ this.y);
        }

        var graphOptions = eval("GraphOptions" + x);
        graphOptions.xAxis.categories = ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3', 'Category 4', 'Category 5'];
        graphOptions.chart.renderTo = 'containerChart'+x;
        graphOptions.series.push(graphSeries);

        new Highcharts.Chart(graphOptions);
```

Comment: Are you getting some error ?

Comment: no, currently I am not getting any script error

Comment: If I had to guess I would say your are not really iterating over your `x` value when you think you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't understand what was your problem but a demo which creates three chart according your data: In for each loop you just need to clear the data arrays and series arrays.

```
for(x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
    var graphSeries = eval("GraphSeries");
        graphSeries.data = [];

    graphSeries.name = "GraphSeries" + x;
    graphSeries.data.push({ y: parseInt(107 + x),   color: 'red' });
    graphSeries.data.push({ y: parseInt(31),    color: 'blue' });
    graphSeries.data.push({ y: parseInt(635),   color: 'green' });
    graphSeries.data.push({ y: parseInt(203),   color: 'yellow' });
    graphSeries.data.push({ y: parseInt(2),     color: 'orange' });
    graphSeries.point.events.click = function() {
        alert ('Category: '+ this.category +', value: '+ this.y);
    }

    var graphOptions = eval("GraphOptions");
        graphOptions.series = [];
    graphOptions.xAxis.categories = ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3', 'Category 4', 'Category 5'];
    graphOptions.chart.renderTo = 'containerChart'+x;
    graphOptions.series.push(graphSeries);

    new Highcharts.Chart(graphOptions);
    }
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/De8MB/1/

Comment: it is odd, because I see the html generated and it is same that in your example an same in all my charts generated, but bars are just painted in last chart.  -   I'm working with jquery-1.7.1.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js, I tested on IE and firefox

Comment: I have only GraphOptions and GraphSeries in my example, did you tried with that? Can you put an example jsfiddle?

Comment: I just change the order of div creation and it worked. http://jsfiddle.net/n6GRZ/4/